# React hooks / lifecycle navigation React-native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Im trying to use react hooks useEffect to load my stored data, from reducer store. I noticed that every time the screen is started for the first time, useEffect works normally. But when it gets focus after running navigation.goBack, the hook does not run again. My doubt is, the state of the application has changed, should the react hook not understand this?

```
const diaryData = useSelector(({diaryState}) => diaryState.data);
const diaryIndex = useSelector(({diaryState}) => diaryState.index);
const [diary, setDiary] = useState(diaryData[diaryIndex]);

 useEffect(() => {
// log is only displayed the first time, when you return with navigation.goBack, it does not work.
    console.log('im here');
    loadDiary();
  });

  const loadDiary = () => {
    setLoad(true);
    setDiary(diaryData[diaryIndex]);
    setLoad(false);
  };
```

Im changing redux store state.data with:

```
 diary.growDimens = growDimens;
 diary.lightingType = lightingType;
 diary.lumens = lumens;

 diaryData[diaryIndex] = diary;
 dispatch(diaryFetchSuccess(diaryData));
```

Comment: At what point do you want your `useEffect` to run?.. Because you also have to add dependencies into `useEffect` to run it whenever there is a change in those dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React Lifecycle for `useEffect` doesn't work like that when you use `navigation.goBack()`. When you do so, the page replaces the top layer from the `stack`, that is, when you go to the next page with your `navigation.navigate()`. One page gets added to the stack, and it gets replaced with the `navigation.goBack()`. It is like closing and opening your eyes.

If you really want `loadDiary()` to function whenever you comeback to the page via `navigation.goBack()`, use either of the two things:

- [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) **[MOST PREFERRED]**: Sometimes we want to run side-effects when a screen is focused. A side effect may involve things like adding an event listener, fetching data, updating document title, etc. While this can be achieved using `focus` and `blur` events, it's not very ergonomic.
- The one which is suggested by B Mohammed. You can use `focus` listener. Just use `navigation` from your props or use [useNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) hook for your `navigation`. The code goes like this:

```js
const navigation = useNavigation();

const loadDiary = () => {
   setLoad(true);
   setDiary(diaryData[diaryIndex]);
   setLoad(false);
};

useEffect(() => {
   const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', event => {
      // This will be triggered, whenever your component is active
      console.log("I'm here");
      loadDiary();
   });

   return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

**Please note:** do not use any other `useEffect()` in any of the cases any more, except once, since `focus` is something which will take care of calling `loadDiary()`, when you **come to the page for the first time** or **from navigation.goBack()**

If you want to get more insight on how you can use some other event listeners, look at this link: [Navigation Events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/)

Comment: useFocusEffect. Thats what i needed. Thx my brother.

Comment: Happy to help @FlávioCosta :)

Answer (score 0):

try with a navigation listener :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = porps.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      loadDiary();
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [props.navigation]);
```